# Leave a body trail with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I've been trying to create an effect using jQuery that when you run the mouse over a div, the whole body moves, leaving a trail along the points it passed. I created a function that enabled the whole body to move, but I couldn't find a way to leave the trail.

I tried to use `.clone()`, but as I'm a beginner with jQuery, I wasn't able to do it right.

Here's the code I'm using to move the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 
$("div").mouseover(function() {
    $("body").animate({
        margin: 50,
    })      
});
  
$("div").mouseout(function() {
    $("body").animate({
        margin: 0,
    })
});      

});      
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite an interesting problem. I have coded the following: http://jsfiddle.net/3Pq8E/

Here I'm just adding the border and removing it - creating a trail.

```
$("div").mouseover(function() {
    $("div").animate({
    margin: 25,
    borderLeftWidth: "50px",
    borderTopWidth: "50px",
  }, 1500 );     
});

$("div").mouseout(function() {
    $("div").animate({
        margin: 0,
    borderLeftWidth: "2px",
    borderTopWidth: "2px",
    })
});
```

Comment: I appreciate that, but it's not exactly what I was looking for. I actually need an effect that leaves a trail of all the elements within the body.

Comment: I understand that you require each element to have this animation once the user enters and leaves the body - check out the new version. I've updated the same to perform the same animation to each element in the body: http://jsfiddle.net/3Pq8E/1/